# SOAPUI my script step is getting overwritten after every execution of my test case

Tags: groovy, soapui

My Groovy script in SOAPUI is positioned between a Property step and a Property Transfer step. The property in both of these steps is the same and referenced in the Groovy script step. When I run the testcase, all 7 steps, the script is overwritten with the return message of the last called REST end point.

Steps include:

1. Rest call
2. property Transfer
3. property
4. groovy script
5. property transfer
6. Rest call
7. property transfer

Can this be a bug or is it a feature?

Comment: what does it mean `the script is overwritten` ?

Comment: When you look at the step's script it disappears between before and after running the test case  i.e overwritten some how.